# How To Add String To List<String>? List<String> is Model In Model

Tags: c#, string, list

Thsi Is My Model:

```
public VoyageReservedViewModel{
               public List<string> preFactorID { get; set; }
                public int Code{ get; set; } }
```

I want to Add String To List <String> by Thsi Code:

```
 VoyageReservedViewModel Obj = new VoyageReservedViewModel();
      foreach (var item in result)
      {    
          Obj.preFactorID.Add("My String Value");
      }
```

But I Reseved This Error:

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
>   Sample.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: My Problem was Add String To List<String>
Its Not About [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: Your problem is the NullReferenceException and the answers in the linked question will guide you how to fix that. The cause is the same from all questions about NRE: you try to work with a reference which is null. period

Comment: BTW you also have some code and when it executes you get the NRE - it is a perfect duplicate

Comment: I can see my Error and msgError but i dont know why that msg shown to me, i had the problem that adding a string to list<string>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to instantiate **`preFactorID`** which is a type of **`List<string>`**

```
   VoyageReservedViewModel Obj = new VoyageReservedViewModel();  
   Obj.preFactorID = new  List<string>(); 
   foreach (var item in result)
   {              
          Obj.preFactorID.Add("My String Value");
   }
```

Comment: That's going to empty his list on each iteration; probably not what he wants.

Comment: Its Worked..
Tnks

Answer (score 1):

You instantiated `VoyageReservedViewModel` but never instantiated its list property `preFactorID`. You can't add to the list if it has not been initialised.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, `preFactorID` property is null! You need to initialize it, like this:

```
 VoyageReservedViewModel Obj = new VoyageReservedViewModel();
 Obj.preFactorID  = new List<string>();
```

Or using the [object initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-objects-by-using-an-object-initializer) like this:

```
VoyageReservedViewModel Obj = new VoyageReservedViewModel{
  preFactorID   = new List<string>()
};
```

**Update** I want to add something to this answer. If you just insert to this list in one specific place, if you add these IDs just in this `foreach` loop and you don't want to edit its values in anywhere else. I suggest that you use other type like `IEnumerable<string>` it gives your code more 'portability' using such a generic portable type. So your code become:

```
public VoyageReservedViewModel
{
   public IEnumerable<string> preFactorID { get; set; }
   public int Code{ get; set; } 
}
VoyageReservedViewModel Obj = new VoyageReservedViewModel();
var list = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in result)
{    
    list.Add("My String Value");
}
obj.preFactorID = list; // List<T> is an IEnumerable<T>
```